# How can make my URL checker program faster?

Tags: c#, html, .net, url

I made a URL checker program which is checked URLs from a list and return valid sub links recursively. It checks all sub links. I have more than 100 main page like this and I would check these sites with all subs. It takes 3 minutes averagely for one site. especially first Html Code (at the sample  string "HtmlCode = client.DownloadString(Link);") takes times, the others faster than first. I would run my program repeatedly and it control links and sending me warning for broken links. How could I faster my program?

```
  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> UrlS = Link_Bul_v2("http://www.asdfhg.com", new List<string>(), new List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>>());
        List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> UrlS2 = Link_Bul_v2("http://www.huuene.com", new List<string>(), new List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>>());

    }



    string UrlSadelesti(string Link)
    {
        return Link.Replace("https://", "").Replace("http://", "").Replace("www.", "");
    }

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    private List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> Link_Bul_v2(string Link, List<string> HList, List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> CList)
    {


        try
        {

            string HtmlCode = client.DownloadString(Link);

            //if(HtmlCode.

            CList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, bool>(Link, true));
            var Link_Short = UrlSadelesti(Link).Split('/')[0];
            //HList.Add(Link_Short);

            string DLink;
            int IndexH = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                IndexH = HtmlCode.IndexOf("href", IndexH);
                if (IndexH == -1) { break; }

                if (HtmlCode[IndexH - 1] == '.')
                {
                    IndexH = IndexH + 1;

                }
                else
                {

                    var IndexD1 = HtmlCode.IndexOf('"', IndexH);

                    var IndexD2 = HtmlCode.IndexOf('"', IndexD1 + 1);

                    var length = IndexD2 - (IndexD1 + 1);

                    DLink = HtmlCode.Substring(IndexD1 + 1, length);

                    IndexH = IndexD2;


                    if ((DLink.Contains(".css") == false))
                    {
                        if (DLink.Contains("http://") || DLink.Contains("https://"))
                        {
                            if (DLink.Contains(Link_Short) == false)
                                continue;

                        }
                        if (DLink.Contains("#"))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        DLink = UrlSadelesti(DLink).Replace(Link_Short, "");

                        if (DLink.Length == 1)
                            continue;

                        if (HList.Count(p => p.Contains(DLink)) == 0)
                        {
                            if (DLink.Contains("http://") || DLink.Contains("https://"))
                            {
                                HList.Add(Link_Short + "/" + DLink);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                HList.Add("http://" + Link_Short + "/" + DLink);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            CList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, bool>(Link, false));
            if (!HList.Contains(Link))
                HList.Add(Link);

            if (UrlSadelesti(Link).Split('/').Count() > 1)
            {
                Link_Bul_v2("http://" + UrlSadelesti(Link).Split('/')[0], HList, CList);
            }
        }
        foreach (string s in HList)
        {
            if (CList.Count(p => p.Key.Contains(s)) == 0)
            {
                Link_Bul_v2(s, HList, CList);
            }
        }
        return CList;

    }
```

Comment: not an answer but Xenu (http://xenus-link-sleuth.en.softonic.com/) looks exactly as what you are trying to do

Comment: thanks, I know there are programs which make this but I'm trying to develop my c#.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to check each link in parallel:
[How to: Write a Simple Parallel.ForEach Loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

...

Parallel.ForEach(links, (currentLink) => 
                            {
                                // Check "currentLink"
                            });

// All links are checked at this point
```

Comment: I tried this but I had "WebClient instances do not support multiple pending" error.

Comment: Make sure you're creating a new `WebClient` instance in each of the parallel threads, or does that not help?